# Creating new channel field error: The page you requested was not found

Tags: ee2, channel, channel-fields

Adding new channel fields always says **"The page you requested was not found."** but editing fields works fine. Everything is working until we installed Profile:Edit module and even uninstalling it did not do the trick. Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the URL in your address bar when you receive that error? Just the bit after your admin.php file.

Comment: /system/index.php?/cp/admin_content/field_edit&S=a86a172e74852c3fe8ae833e6e19b87d

Comment: Are you adding and editing channel fields using native tools or an add-on? Your URL is missing the `group_id` parameter which tells ExpressionEngine which Field Group you are trying to create a new channel in. If you are using the native Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields tools, please list any extensions you have installed.

Comment: I'm adding it using the native tools. And yes figure the group id issue too. I have installed Profile:Edit, Cartthrob, Channel Images, Channel Files, Channel Videos, DataGrab, Low Search, Tagger and Freemember. And the latest add-on that I have installed was Profile:Edit but it was still working right after I installed it.

Comment: All good now, it seems that the hosting has the issues. Thanks @DerekJones for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, did they provide details? If so you could give it as an answer to your question to help someone with similar environmental issues in the future.

Comment: Some **mod_security** rules that needs to be disabled but they did not give any details on the specific rules that cause it.